# Angularjs vs IE 8 vs IE 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make my web application based on Angularjs work in IE8 and IE11.
After a lot of search, i am asking my question here: is it possible to make an Angularjs application work in IE11? and into IE11 ?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 13):

I had a problem while loading a angularjs file on IE. It worked perfeclty as expected on Chrome and Firefox but was giving error as angular not defined and what not. After searching on Internet I applied following fix to my code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

and now it displays the page.

Comment: For anyone having trouble with IE and `angular` being undefined. This is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should work and how you achieve that will depend on the application you are writing. Basically, you have to add extra codes to handle IE8. The [AngularJS guide on IE](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) should be a good place to start.

However, there could be situations where you run into problems. For example, when you want to use the "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag. An option could be to use the [Google Frame plugin](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started) but Google has stopped updates on it from January 2014.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question needs to be more precise about **What is wrong with IE11?**

I have personally created angularjs applications that works from IE8+ and on all other browsers like chrome, safari, firefox, opera. With all these browsers angular worked just fine.

It is important to mentioned that Microsoft broke the "Internet Explorer" inheritance meaning that internally IE11 is completely different from all other previous versions of IE but being the most advance version of Internet Explorer Angular does not need any particular "adaptation" to work with this browser.

If there is anything you should be worry it is IE8 :) and I am **not** saying this because of angular but because of IE8 itself.